# When submitting a form Laravel returns "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I'm submit a form Laravel returns "The page has expired due to inactivity.

Please refresh and try again. "

This are the most important parts of my code (I think)

**message.php:**

```
public function uploadMessage()
{
    $query = DB::table('users')->select('id')->where('email', Auth::user()->email)->first();
    $userID = $query->id;

    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $query = DB::table('message')->insert(['userID' => $userID, 'message' => $message]);
}
```

**Home.blade.php**
    `

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $mess->uploadMessage();
}
?>

<form method="post" class="form-insert">
                    <h3 class="form-titel">Make your status Fresh</h3>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                        <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="message">Text...</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">

                </form>`
```

Comment: Go to config/session.php and check lifetime of session. Maybe it is solution.

Comment: @AdamKozlowski The session lifetime is set at 120. Haven't touched that ever.

Comment: add this to your form  {{ csrf_field() }}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use in your form in html view token:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Just paste this csrf_field. It must be between `<form>` tags.
It is because of VerifyCsrfToken.
Read more:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Comment: Laravel 5.6+ simplifies this to ```@csrf```

Comment: @NerdyGinger - nice tip, thank you very much! `[+1]`

Answer (score 1):

Put `@csrf` after opening form tag in your blade file.